# Collectionview cell not aligning with collectionview frame

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am trying to create a fullscreen collection view cell. The collection view is pinned to the edges of the parent view. But the collectionview cells are not aligning with the collectionview frame which is required. Can somebody help?

[View hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMHIK.png)

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrbeO.png)

```
private func setupPageCollectionView() {
        
        let flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = .red
    
        pageCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        pageCollectionView.register(MyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MyCell.reuseIdentifier)
        pageCollectionView.delegate = self
        pageCollectionView.dataSource = self
        pageCollectionView.decelerationRate = .fast
        pageCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        pageCollectionView.backgroundColor = .blue
        self.view.addSubview(pageCollectionView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pageCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            pageCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            pageCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            pageCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return collectionView.bounds.size
    }
```

Comment: You must be doing something that you have not shown us... using this code: https://pastebin.com/eXUK84Rn ... and scrolling a little bit to show the first two cells, I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyvPn.png

Answer (score -1):

Check the collectionView's contentInsets, contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior and (most likely) insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea.

Answer (score -1):

Does `collectionView.bounds.size` return the right size?

Maybe there is some top padding in the cell subclass?

Try to implement `insetForSectionAt` from `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    .zero
}
```